# How can i analise millions of strings that merge into each other?

Tags: c#, string, list

I have millions of strings, around 8GB worth of HEX; each string is 3.2kb in length.

Each of these strings contains multiple parts of data I need to extract.

This is an example of one such string:

> GPGGA,104644.091,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*43$GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32Header Test.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ$GPGGA,104645.091,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*42$GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32Header Test.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ ÿÿ!ÿÿ"ÿÿ#ÿÿ$ÿÿ%ÿÿ&ÿÿ'ÿÿ(ÿÿ)ÿÿ*ÿÿ+ÿÿ,ÿÿ-ÿÿ.ÿÿ/ÿÿ0ÿÿ1ÿÿ$GPGGA,104646.091,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*41$GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32Header Test2ÿÿ3ÿÿ4ÿÿ5ÿÿ6ÿÿ7ÿÿ8ÿÿ9ÿÿ:ÿÿ;ÿÿ<ÿÿ=ÿÿ>ÿÿ?ÿÿ@ÿÿAÿÿBÿÿCÿÿDÿÿEÿÿFÿÿGÿÿHÿÿIÿÿJÿÿ$GPGGA,104647.091,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*40$GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32Header TestKÿÿLÿÿMÿÿNÿÿOÿÿPÿÿQÿÿRÿÿSÿÿTÿÿUÿÿVÿÿWÿÿXÿÿYÿÿZÿÿ[ÿÿ\ÿÿ]ÿÿ^ÿÿ_ÿÿ`ÿÿaÿÿbÿÿcÿÿ$GPGGA,104648.091,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*4F$GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32Header Testdÿÿeÿÿfÿÿgÿÿhÿÿiÿÿjÿÿkÿÿlÿÿmÿÿnÿÿoÿÿpÿÿqÿÿrÿÿsÿÿtÿÿuÿÿvÿÿwÿÿxÿÿyÿÿzÿÿ{ÿÿ|ÿÿ$GPGGA,104649.091,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*4E$GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32Header Test}ÿÿ~ÿÿ.ÿÿ€ÿÿ.ÿÿ‚ÿÿƒÿÿ„ÿÿ…ÿÿ†ÿÿ‡ÿÿˆÿÿ‰ÿÿŠÿÿ‹ÿÿŒÿÿ.ÿÿŽÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ‘ÿÿ’ÿÿ“ÿÿ”ÿÿ•ÿÿ$GPGGA,104650.091,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*46$GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32Head

as you can see it is pretty much this repeated:

> GPGGA,104644.091,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*43$GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32Header Test.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ$GPGGA,104645.091,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*42$GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32Header Test.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ ÿÿ!ÿÿ"ÿÿ#ÿÿ$ÿÿ%ÿÿ&ÿÿ'ÿÿ(ÿÿ)ÿÿ*ÿÿ+ÿÿ,ÿÿ-ÿÿ.ÿÿ/ÿÿ0ÿÿ1ÿÿ

I want to separate this string into two lists like this:

_GPSList

```
$GPGGA,104644.091,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*43
$GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*
$GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N
```

_WavList

```
32HeaderTest.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ
32HeaderTest.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ.ÿÿ ÿÿ!ÿÿ"ÿÿ#ÿÿ$ÿÿ%ÿÿ&ÿÿ'ÿÿ(ÿÿ)ÿÿ*ÿÿ+ÿÿ,ÿÿ-ÿÿ.ÿÿ/ÿÿ0ÿÿ1ÿÿ
```

Issue 1: 
This repetition isn't containing within a single string, it overflows into the next string. so if some data crosses the end and start of two strings how to I deal with that?

Issue 2: How do I analyse the string and extract only the parts I need?

Comment: Whatever you're getting this data from seems to think a bunch of binary data should be decoded as Windows-1252 characters. This is going to give you a hard time if there are any control characters in there. If possible, go back to the source and ask them to deliver the data *properly*, as an actual hexstring. Or, possibly, you are the one getting things wrong by treating the file as text -- when it's not, and just contains printable text every so often.

Comment: 8GB of Alien Language, but simply not plain HEX for sure!

Comment: It's a mixture of GPS and Raw WAV data. It's data I have produced. I have the actual HEX but I figured it might be easier for people to see what I needed with the ASCII representation of it

Comment: Have u tried  splitting the string on "$"

Comment: I haven't but only because that wouldn't give me what I wanted. if I did that I would get GPS and WAV data mixed together. Thanks :)

Comment: before posting a probable solution, i would wanna know: Wav data always starts with `HeaderTest` and `$` is the only differentiating factor here?

Comment: Wav data starts with  *xxheader where xx is a sequential number and GPS starts with $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I'm providing is not a complete answer but more like an idea which might help you get what you want.

Everything else which I present is an assumption on my behalf.

```
//Assuming your data is stored in a file "yourdatafile"
//Splitting all the text on "$" assuming this will separate GPSData
string[] splittedstring = File.ReadAllText("yourdatafile").Split('$');
//I found an extra string lingering in the sample you provided
//because I splitted on "$", so you gotta take that into account

var GPSList = new List<string>();
var WAVList = new List<string>();

foreach (var str in splittedstring)
{
    //So if the string contains "Header" we would want to separate it from GPS data
    if (str.Contains("Header"))
    {
       string temp = str.Remove(str.IndexOf("Header"));
       int indexOfAsterisk = temp.LastIndexOf("*");
       string stringBeforeAsterisk = str.Substring(0, indexOfAsterisk + 1);
       string stringAfterAsterisk = str.Replace(stringBeforeAsterisk, "");
       WAVList.Add(stringAfterAsterisk);
       GPSList.Add("$" + stringBeforeAsterisk);
    }
    else
       GPSList.Add("$" + str);
}
```

This provides the exact output as you need, only exception is with that extra string. Also some non-standard characters might look like black blocks.